# Haskell STM : Main thread will not exit until child thread completes execution

Tags: multithreading, haskell, stm

In the following program, I want that main thread will not exit until all its child threads complete execution. Please note that I have used bang patterns to evaluate the Fibonacci call so that it returns an evaluated thunk to main thread.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Main
where

import Control.Concurrent.STM 
import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO

nfib :: Int -> Int
nfib n | n <= 2 = 1
       | otherwise = (n1 + n2 )
                     where n1 = nfib (n-1)
                           n2 = nfib (n-2)

type TInt = TVar Int

updateNum :: TInt -> Int -> STM()
updateNum n v = do writeTVar n v

updateTransaction :: TInt -> Int -> IO ()
updateTransaction n v = do 
        atomically $ do
             updateNum n v

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    n <- newTVarIO 10

    forkIO $ do             
        let v = 30
        let !x = nfib v
        updateTransaction n x

    forkIO $ do             
        let v = 15
        let !x = nfib v
        updateTransaction n x

    forkIO $ do             
        let v = 25
        let !x = nfib v
        updateTransaction n x   

    nv <- readTVarIO n
    putStrLn ("Fib number of "  ++ " = " ++ (show nv))  

    nv <-  readTVarIO n
    putStrLn ("Fib number of "  ++ " = " ++ (show nv))

    nv <-  readTVarIO n
    putStrLn ("Fib number of "  ++ " = " ++ (show nv))
```

---

I have tired to solve this problem as per [link] ([Haskell MVar : How to execute shortest job first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741439/haskell-mvar-how-to-execute-shortest-job-first)). I don't know whether approach is correct not not and also getting an error when try to print the value of TMVar. 
Here is the code :-  (nfib is same as above)

```
type TMInt = TMVar Int

updateNum1 :: TMInt -> Int -> STM()
updateNum1 n v = do putTMVar n v

updateTransaction1 :: TMInt -> Int -> IO ()
updateTransaction1 n v = do 
        atomically $ do
            updateNum1 n v

main1 :: IO ()
main1 = do 
    n <- newTMVarIO 0
    forkIO $ do             
        let v = 30
        let !x = nfib v
        updateTransaction1 n x

    forkIO $ do             
        let v = 15
        let !x = nfib v
        updateTransaction1 n x

    forkIO $ do             
        let v = 25
        let !x = nfib v
        updateTransaction1 n x  

    -- t <- takeTMVar n
    -- putStrLn( "result: " ++ (show t))
```

** Error is as follows:-

```
Couldn't match type `STM' with `IO'
Expected type: IO Int
     Actual type: STM Int
In the return type of a call of `takeTMVar'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: t <- takeTMVar n
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: In this code several `STM` transactions are run which perform a single read or a single write on a `TVar`. This looks weird. There are no guarantees on the ordering of these writes w.r.t. the reads, so any intermediate value can be read, e.g. `10,10,10`.

Comment: @Chi, in the first case (with TVar), if I add a thread delay e.g. `threadDelay (10^6 * 4)  nv <- readTVarIO n   putStrLn ("Fib number of "  ++ " = " ++ (show nv))` then it shows the last updated value i.e. 832040 (Fib 30). Otherwise it shows values as 10 610 and 610 (610 is value of Fib 15)

Comment: That's fine, if your aim is to observe the effects of race conditions. Still, I wonder why you didn't use plain `IOVar`s instead of `TVar`s -- you are not really using transactions here.

Comment: @Chi I have used TVar instead of IOVar, just to avoid lock related problems (although not applicable particularly in this code). I wanted to check the total execution time for set of read and write transactions (in a different program). But I couldn't do so, as the main thread exits before the completion of child threads. How to overcome this problem. Is there any alternative other than TMVar?

Comment: There is some discussion on that at the end of http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent.html in "Terminating the program"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main1` is in `IO` but `takeTMVar` returns an `STM Int`. You need to run the transaction:

```
t <- atomically $ takeTMVar n
putStrLn( "result: " ++ (show t))
```